# Android navigation component: how save fragment state

Tags: android, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I use bottomNavigationView and navigation component. Please tell me how I don't destroy the fragment after switching to another tab and return to the old one? For example I have three tabs - A, B, C. My start tab is A. After I navigate to B, then return A. When I return to tab A, I do not want it to be re-created. How do it? Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per the [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773), Navigation does not directly support multiple back stacks - i.e., saving the state of stack B when you go back to B from A or C since Fragments do not support multiple back stacks.

As per [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773#comment29):

> The NavigationAdvancedSample is now available at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample
>
> This sample uses multiple NavHostFragments, one for each bottom navigation tab, to work around the current limitations of the Fragment API in supporting multiple back stacks.
>
> We'll be proceeding with the Fragment API to support multiple back stacks and the Navigation API to plug into it once created, which will remove the need for anything like the `NavigationExtensions.kt` file. We'll continue to use this issue to track that work.

Therefore you can use the NavigationAdvancedSample approach in your app right now and star the issue so that you get updates for when the underlying issue is resolved and direct support is added to Navigation.

Comment: So a simple feature like keeping 3 screens in memory required a new 'advanced' sample? You have got to be kidding

Comment: @Radu - it isn't just the three Fragments, it is a whole back stack associated with each tab (and the state of every one of *those* Fragments). FragmentManager only stores the state of things directly on the back stack (i.e., you can hit the system back button to get back to them), which isn't the case for bottom nav, where you want users to be able to swap between tabs without losing state.

Comment: After all, maybe it is not that bad of an idea!
my problem was that I head to redeclare fragments in each nav graphs.

Comment: @AminKeshavarzian - you can also use an [`<include>` tag](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs#include) to reference a separate graph instead of copy/pasting.

Comment: @ianhanniballake you are right, but I was referring to mostly a single fragment because it wouldn't make sense to include a large graph just to add a destination from it.the trick, however, was to use identical ids.

Comment: i use Navigation Advanced Sample and that is not save instance of fragment something is behind of this sample for saving instance

Comment: @AliKhaki - it does indeed save and restore state correctly. You should test your Fragments in other cases, such as being put on the back stack or when rotating your device to ensure that your Fragment is written correctly to restore its state.

Comment: The one solution that I works me was implement ViewModel + LiveData in each fragment where needish

Comment: they say this is coming in 2.3, were on 2.2 do i do the advance sample just to change it later? who knows

Comment: @ianhanniballake can you please let me know, how can I use it with the navigation view?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Using this solution doesn't generate SafeArgs and FragmentDirection bindings. Ca you please help how can this be fixed?

Comment: This class from the sample that @ianhanniballake is talking about, does not work. All it does it maintain the back stack and the state when you press back, that's it. Clicking on the bottom nav item, re-creates the fragment again. I fail to understand 250 lines of code for I don't know what.

Comment: @Uday - the [`setupItemReselected()`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt#L181) method is where you'd want to customize the reselection behavior. You could just do nothing if that's what is appropriate for your app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hello sir, any updates on this matter or folk are still confined to the advanced nav sample approach? Many thanks.

Comment: I almost gave up on navigation architecture components. Google should also mention the limitation of their new APIs that will make life of developer easier to decide which API is more feasible to use in longer run.

Comment: Why all the samples are now in Kotlin?. Its highly unreadable.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Hi Ian, does this solution still the most actual in context of 'navigation component'?

Comment: The latest nav library v: 2.4.0-alpha01 does support multiple back stacks out of the box [Multiple Back Stack](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f).

Comment: It took me days trying to save the state of the fragment until I saw your answer, thank you

Comment: this issue was fixed with navigation in Jetpack Compose

Comment: @ianhanniballake is this fixed now? How can save fragment states when moving from one fragment to another

Comment: @amodkanthe - you'd want to follow the [guide to saving your fragment's state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state).

Comment: not working with viewBinding. any solution ?

Comment: Can some one validate below for me? 
I would have bottom navigation, viewpager, tab layout(hide this). On bottom navigation item click set the viewpager selected item. Thats is
 binding.contentMain.bottomNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
viewPager.currentItem = position
}
I am sure with this approach I can get the job done. But what can be wrong with this approach?

Comment: Nav version 2.5.3: the only main graph startDestination target fragment is keeping in memory, other fragments are still have been recreated. Useless fix, Google is not ok here too.

Answer (score 7):

In case you can deal with destroying fragment, but want to save ViewModel, you can scope it into the Navigation Graph:

```
private val viewModel: FavouritesViewModel by 
    navGraphViewModels(R.id.mobile_navigation) {
        viewModelFactory
    }
```

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#share_ui-related_data_between_destinations_with_viewmodel)

**EDIT**

As @SpiralDev noted, using Hilt simplifies a bit:

```
private val viewModel: MainViewModel by 
    navGraphViewModels(R.id.mobile_navigation) {
         defaultViewModelProviderFactory     
    }
```

Comment: For DaggerHilt: `private val viewModel: MainViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.my_nav) {
        defaultViewModelProviderFactory
    }`

Answer (score 5):

just use navigation component version 2.4.0-alpha01 or above

Comment: Works fine, But it clears all the variables.

Comment: yeah you need to handle it on viewmodel as usual, and if you using scrollview dont forget to add id.

Comment: Yup, it is working fine with saving UI state.

Comment: How can I call API for button click of fragment from viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Using last version of fragment navigation component, handle fragment states itself. see [this sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)

**Old:**

```
class BaseViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val bundleFromFragment = MutableLiveData<Bundle>()
}


class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel () {

   ... HomeViewModel logic
}
```

inside home fragment (tab of bottom navigation)

```
private var viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.bundleFromFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      
        val message = it.getString("ARGUMENT_MESSAGE", "")
       binding.edtName.text = message
    })
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    viewModel.bundleFromFragment.value = bundleOf(
        "ARGUMENT_MESSAGE" to binding.edtName.text.toString(),
        "SCROLL_POSITION" to binding.scrollable.scrollY
    )
}
```

You can do this pattern for all fragments inside bottom navigation

Comment: But I DON"T use the friking bottom navigation bar - what then!

Answer (score -1):

**Update 2021**
use version 2.4.0-alpha05 or above.
don't use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/4797289) or other etc.

Answer (score -4):

This can be achieved using Fragment show/hide logic.

```
private val bottomFragmentMap = hashMapOf<Int, Fragment>()
bottomFragmentMap[0] = FragmentA.newInstance()
bottomFragmentMap[1] = FragmentB.newInstance()
bottomFragmentMap[2] = FragmentC.newInstance()
bottomFragmentMap[3] = FragmentD.newInstance()


private fun loadFragment(fragmentIndex: Int) {
    val fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

    val bottomFragment = bottomFragmentMap[fragmentIndex]!!

    // first time case. Add to container
    if (!bottomFragment.isAdded) {
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, bottomFragment)
    }

    // hide remaining fragments
    for ((key, value) in bottomFragmentMap) {
        if (key == fragmentIndex) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(value)
        } else if (value.isVisible) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(value)
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Declare fragment on the activity & create fragment instance on onCreate method, then pass the fragment instance in updateFragment method. Create as many fragment instances as required corresponding to bottom navigation listener item id.

```
Fragment fragmentA;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

fragmentA = new Fragment();
updateFragment(fragmentA);
}

public void updateFragment(Fragment fragment) {
FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.layoutFragment, fragment);
transaction.commit();
}
```

Furthermore be sure you are using android.support.v4.app.Fragment and calling getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: The OP said they were using the [Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation). You don't directly do FragmentTransactions when you use Navigation.

Comment: Yes I understand but OP wants to switch tabs only. I guess this must be a better approach.