# How to save fragment state while navigating with navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to create a single activity app using android architecture components. I have a fragment A which has some textfields, when user pushes a button I navigate to fragment B where he uploads and edits some images after that app navigates back to A using code like this:

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_from_B_to_A, dataBundle)`

When navigating back B passes some data to A using `dataBundle`. The problem with this is all the textfields reset because Fragment A is basically recreated from scratch. I read somewhere that a developer from google suggests that you can just save view in a var instead of inflating it everytime. So tried doing that:

```
private var savedViewInstance: View? = null

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return if (savedViewInstance != null) {
        savedViewInstance
    } else {
        savedViewInstance =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_professional_details, container, false)
        savedViewInstance
    }
}
```

But this does not work, all the textfields reset when navigating back to A. What am I doing wrong? What is proper way of handling cases like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66262120/4718406

Answer (score 15):

I will answer your questions one by one.

> But this does not work, all the textfields reset when navigating back
>   to A. What am I doing wrong?

From FragmentB, when users finish their work and the app call the below method to return FragmentA.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_from_B_to_A, dataBundle)
```

You expected that the app will bring users back to FragmentA, but the actual result is a new FragmentA is created and put on the top of the back stack. Now the back stack will be like this.

```
FragmentA (new instance)
FragmentB
FragmentA (old instance)
```

That why you see all textfields reset, because it is a totally new instance of FragmentA.

> What is proper way of handling cases like this?

You want to start a fragment, then receive result form that fragment, it seems like `startActivityForResult` method of Activity.

In [Android Dev Summit 2019 - Architecture Components](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWHfLvlmBbs&t=476s), at *2:43*, there is a question for Android developers.

> Can we have something like `startFragmentForResult` for the Navigation
>   Controller?

The answer is they are working on it, and this feature will be available in future.

Back to your problem, here is my solution.

**Step 1:** Create a class called `SharedViewModel`

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // This is the data bundle from fragment B to A
    val bundleFromFragmentBToFragmentA = MutableLiveData<Bundle>()
}
```

**Step 2:** Add these lines of code to FragmentA

```
private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.bundleFromFragmentBToFragmentA.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        // This will execute when fragment B set data for `bundleFromFragmentBToFragmentA`
        // TODO: Write your logic here to handle data sent from FragmentB
        val message = it.getString("ARGUMENT_MESSAGE", "")
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    })
}
```

**Step 3:** Add these lines of code to FragmentB

```
// 1. Declare this as class's variable
private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel

// 2. Use the following code when you want to return FragmentA           
// findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_from_B_to_A) // Do not use this one

// Set data for `bundleFromFragmentBToFragmentA`
val data = Bundle().apply { putString("ARGUMENT_MESSAGE", "Hello from FragmentB") }
viewModel.bundleFromFragmentBToFragmentA.value = data

// Pop itself from back stack to return FragmentA
requireActivity().onBackPressed()
```

Comment: Hey, I'm doing exactly as you've said but my fragment still doesn't save view state. Do i need to keep the code i posted in my question?

Comment: @AmolBorkar Can you show fragment_professional_details.xml file and the fragment class as well.

Comment: I've added the code in the question back, it works fine now, Thanks!

Comment: Nice workaround, but I really wait until they will fix it

Comment: And finally we can use startFragmentForResult now! ))

Comment: @SonTruong Hi, I am facing the same problem (I do not send data between fragments) but I have a bottom navigation bar and with help on navigation component I switch between fragments. I think new instance keeps getting created so I cannot restore my fragments state. How can I pop my fragment from stack to restore state? I do not understand Java so please help

Answer (score 11):

If you want to keep scroll view's position after popping back, make sure you put ID to views such as `NestedScrollView` even if it's not needed on the code level:

```
android:id="@+id/some_id"
```

This way when the `Fragment` returned from the backstack, scroll positions are maintained.

Comment: Perfect for saving scroll state

Comment: I have set `id` to every view i have in my fragment but not working. am i missing anything?

Comment: I need to mention that the id MUST be UNIQUE. I did have an id but the state is still lost. this is because there was a duplicate of my ID in the same UI.

Answer (score 10):

Just a little thing, if your views don't have id, state will not be kept!

> A view needs an ID to retain its state. This ID must be unique within
> the fragment and its view hierarchy. Views without an ID cannot retain
> their state.

Have a look at google official docs [View state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state#view)

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @obey this happened in my case

Comment: This worked for me for EditText!, TextView keep loosing its state.

Comment: it did not work for me. i set id to every view i have in my fragment layout but still it looks like fragment is making new view/state. i'm using navigation component by the way if it gives you any clue whats really going on.

Comment: This answer solved my issue, I've been debugging the problem all day. I've been losing my checkbox check state when I'm navigating back to a fragment. I changed the ID of the view to a unique one and my state is saved. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 8):

In frag A, I create two global variables

```
private var mRootView: ViewGroup? = null
private var mIsFirstLoad = false
```

In onCreateView() of frag A, I write

```
_binding = FragmentDashBoardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    if (mRootView == null) {
        mRootView = _binding?.root
        mIsFirstLoad = true
    } else {
        mIsFirstLoad = false
    }
    return mRootView
```

In onViewCreated() of frag A, I check the value of "mIsFirstLoad"

```
if(mIsFirstLoad) {
    initAdapter()
    getMovies()
} else {
    //Continue with previously initialised variables. e.g. adapter   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use base fragment, but it's just workaround. Actually, navigation component is still buggy. Here is an [issue](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/530) on GitHub.
Example:

```
class SearchFragment : BaseBottomTabFragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentSearchBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.buttonDynamicTitleNavigate.setOnClickListener {
            navigateWithAction(
                SearchFragmentDirections.actionSearchFragmentToDynamicTitleFragment(
                    binding.editTextTitle.text.toString()
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Code snipped from: [This project](https://github.com/furkanaskin/TrickyNavigationSample)

Comment: Indeed it's buggy

Comment: Для меня сработало

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate) of Google document.

If your action is fragmentA -> fragmentB -> fragmentC. then from fragmentC back to  fragmentA, you want to remove fragmentC, fragmentB and keep fragmentA's state.

So you should:

1. add an action from fragmentC to fragmentA
2. set the action that "popUpTo" be fragmentA and popUpToInclusive be true.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need create ViewModels scoped to a Navigation Graph.

Check this nice guide and you can keep your navigation component. Its very easy to implement and works for me!!
https://medium.com/sprinthub/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-use-nav-graph-scoped-viewmodels-cf82de4545ed