# fragment navigation vs fragment container

Tags: android, android-fragments

using fragment navigation, when I move temp1 to temp2 and temp2 to temp1 again, I see the fragment is generated newly. But when I use fragmentManager.replace, it reuse the fragment that I already used.

*resuing code*

```
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    private  var currentFragment: Fragment?=null
    private  var homeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private  var temp1Fragment =Temp1Fragment()
    private  var temp2Fragment= Temp2Fragment()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        initBottomNavItemClick()
        currentFragment = homeFragment
    }


    private fun initBottomNavItemClick(){
        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.homeFragment->{
                //    findNavController(R.id.navFragment).navigate(R.id.homeNavFragment)
                    currentFragment = homeFragment
                    changeFragment(this,binding.fragmentContainer,currentFragment!!)
                }
                R.id.tempFragment1->{
                   // findNavController(R.id.navFragment).navigate(R.id.temp1NavFragment)
                    currentFragment = temp1Fragment
                    changeFragment(this,binding.fragmentContainer,currentFragment!!)
                }
                R.id.tempFragment2->{
                   // findNavController(R.id.navFragment).navigate(R.id.temp2NavFragment)
                    currentFragment = temp2Fragment
                    changeFragment(this,binding.fragmentContainer,currentFragment!!)
                }
            }

            true
        }
    }
```

So when I use fragmentManager, I can preserve the recyclerview position when I come back, but not fragment navigation. fragment navigation generates a new fragment and the position start at 0.
is fragment navigation possible to keep the previous status not generating newly?

Comment: with only NavigationComponent it will not be possible [more info here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/issues/530), use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) instead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer your question in two part.

- Solution
- Explanation

**Solution**

Do not inflate view every time you are coming back to previous fragment. Save `View` in a local variable and inflate it only once. Suggested by [Ian Lanke](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1103522856535638016)

```
private var savedViewInstance: View? = null

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return if (savedViewInstance != null) {
        savedViewInstance
    } else {
        savedViewInstance =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_professional_details, container, false)
        savedViewInstance
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

Let's understand life cycle of a fragment under navigation architecture.

Scenario: We are taking two fragments, HomeFragment and DashboardFragment. Both fragments belong to same NavGraph and start destination is Home Fragment.

***Fragment Life Cycle on launching of app-***

> HomeFragment: onAttach:
>
> HomeFragment: onCreate:
>
> HomeFragment: onCreateView:
>
> HomeFragment: onViewCreated:
>
> HomeFragment: onActivityCreated:
>
> HomeFragment: onStart:
>
> HomeFragment: onResume:

***On Navigation: Home Fragment ---> Dashboard Fragment***

> DashboardFragment: onAttach:
>
> DashboardFragment: onCreate:
>
> DashboardFragment: onCreateView:
>
> DashboardFragment: onViewCreated:
>
> DashboardFragment: onActivityCreated:
>
> DashboardFragment: onStart:
>
> DashboardFragment: onResume:
>
> HomeFragment: onPause:
>
> HomeFragment: onStop:
>
> HomeFragment: onDestroyView:

***On Navigation: Dashboard Fragment ---> Home Fragment***

> HomeFragment: onAttach:
>
> HomeFragment: onCreate:
>
> HomeFragment: onCreateView:
>
> HomeFragment: onViewCreated:
>
> HomeFragment: onActivityCreated:
>
> HomeFragment: onStart:
>
> HomeFragment: onResume:
>
> DashboardFragment: onPause:
>
> DashboardFragment: onStop:
>
> ***HomeFragment: onDestroy:***
>
> DashboardFragment: onDestroyView:
>
> DashboardFragment: onDestroy:

If we are saving view on intial `HomeFragment: onCreateView()` and inflating same view every time for next call of `HomeFragment: onCreateView()`, we can get old view restored.

If you notice `HomeFragment: onDestroy()` will be called but after `HomeFragment: onViewCreated()` has called. Calling of HomeFragment: onDestroy() is just destroying old instance of HomeFragment.

I still believe this way of doing things are not best practice but it will be until, Google will come up something like `onFragemntRestore()`.

To actually update the view, you must need to ViewModel and observe the changes to change in the views.

For more information you go can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629541/how-to-save-fragment-state-while-navigating-with-navigation-component) thread.
happy coding !