# Stop fragment refresh in bottom nav using navhost

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

This problem has been asked a few times now, but we are in 2020 now, did anyone find a good usable solution to this yet?

I want to be able to navigate using the bottom navigation control without refreshing the fragment each time they are selected. Here is what I have currently:

navigation/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="com.org.ftech.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:name="com.org.ftech.fragment.NewsFragment"
        android:label="News"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_news"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/markets"
        android:name="com.org.ftech.fragment.MarketsFragment"
        android:label="Markets"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_markets"/>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/explore"
        android:name="com.org.ftech.ExploreFragment"
        android:label="Explore"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_explore"/>
</navigation>
```

activity_mail.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/main" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/nav"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/main">

        </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        app:menu="@menu/main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout? = null
    private var navigationView: NavigationView? = null
    private var bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView? = null
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView)
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView)

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.markets, R.id.explore, R.id.news, R.id.home), drawerLayout)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigationView)
            .setupWithNavController(navController)

        findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
            .setupWithNavController(navController)

    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        if (item.itemId == R.id.search) {
            startActivity(Intent(applicationContext, SearchableActivity::class.java))
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

In the fragment I am making a few calls to my services to fetch the data in `onCreateView`, when resuming the fragment I am assuming those calls will not longer be executed and the state of the fragment should be preserved.

Comment: what about using nav host for each item in bottom navigation and on clicking of the icon you change their visibility. I have done that and working perfectly.

Comment: @Abdul can you provide a sample on changing the visibility for those of us who use a nav host?

Comment: check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325054/4797289 is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new DashboardFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new NotificationsFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = fragment1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1, "1").commit();

    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Or You can follow Google's recommended solution: [Google Link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

Comment: Many of us are using the nav Host xml where our fragments get defined. Any suggestions on applying this solution to that newer version since we wouldn't explicitly create fragments in the activity in code directly

Comment: @baskInEminence what is you requirements? Please explain me.

Comment: I have a navigation xml which lists all of my fragments (following latest android pattern for navigation). My activity main xml uses a androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment element with the key value (app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"). The main activity does not create any fragments, only minor setup. 
findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView).setupWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment)). The R.id.fragment is the NavHostFragment I mentioned earlier. This latest android pattern is different from your provided solution where fragments are manually created

Comment: @baskInEminence he wants manual process. Btw if you want to more simplify please follow this link: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah thats just a generic tutorial on how to set it up. It doesn't dive into how to ensure the fragment doesn't refresh

Comment: Created a solution using google's recommended answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/3316842

Comment: Please any idea on how to upgrade to multiple backstacks?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68042591/problem-upgrading-my-fragments-navigation-versionfrom-2-3-5-to-2-4-0-alpha03

Answer (score 11):

**Kotlin 2020 Google's Recommended Solution**

Many of these solutions call the Fragment constructor in the Main Activity. However, following Google's recommended pattern, this is not needed.

**Setup Navigation Graph Tabs**

Firstly create a [navigation graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) xml for each of your tabs under the `res/navigation` directory.

Filename: tab0.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tab0"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA"
    tools:ignore="UnusedNavigation">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:label="@string/fragment_A_title"
        android:name="com.app.subdomain.fragA"
    >
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Repeat the above template for your other tabs. Important all fragments and the navigation graph has an id (e.g. @+id/tab0, @+id/fragmentA).

**Setup Bottom Navigation View**

Ensure the navigation ids are the same as the ones specified on the bottom menu xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="@string/fragment_A_title"
        android:id="@+id/tab0"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_book_24"/>

    <item android:title="@string/fragment_B_title"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_alert_24"/>

    <item android:title="@string/fragment_C_title"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_book_24"/>

    <item android:title="@string/fragment_D_title"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_more_horiz_24"/>

</menu>
```

**Setup Activity Main XML**

Ensure `FragmentContainerView` is being used and not `<fragment` and do not set the app:navGraph attribute. This will set later in code

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
      android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
      android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:defaultNavHost="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/main_toolbar"
/>
```

**Main Activity XML**

Copy over the following Code into your main activity Kotlin file and call `setupBottomNavigationBar` within OnCreateView. Ensure you navGraphIds use `R.navigation.whatever` and not `R.id.whatever`

```
private lateinit var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>

private fun setupBottomNavigationBar() {
  val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigationView)
  val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.tab0, R.navigation.tab1, R.navigation.tab2, R.navigation.tab3)
  val controller = bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(
      navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
      fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
      containerId = R.id.fragmentContainerView,
      intent = intent
  )
  controller.observe(this, { navController ->
      val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.main_toolbar)
      val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navGraphIds.toSet())
      NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration)
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
  })
  currentNavController = controller
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
  return currentNavController?.value?.navigateUp() ?: false
}
```

**Copy NavigationExtensions.kt File**

Copy the following [file](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) to your codebase

[EDIT] The above link is broken. Found it in a forked [repo](https://github.com/matthewzhang007/android-architecture-components/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt)

**Source**

- Google's [Solution](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample)

Comment: This is the right way to go in 2020, I am using this `navigation` component in my application now.

Comment: I have followed your guide, very helpful. Unfortunately navigation works exactly the same as before, all fragments are being recreated. Any suggestions or did I misunderstood what  the google solution was supposed to do.

Comment: Can you provide this NavigationExtensions.kt File, given link is broken

Comment: @AnzyShQ Thank you for the comment. Found it in a forked repo. Updated Answer

Comment: don't use this way, you need the update libs. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69325054/4797289

Comment: @RasoulMiri Although the new alpha version may fix it, it's still an alpha release. They keep publishing a new alpha for this version every 2 weeks. Just keep that in mind when deploying alpha changes with your production code. I am happy to see Google has addressed at least looked into this matter

Answer (score 11):

The simple solution to stop refreshing on multiple clicks on the same navigation item could be

```
 binding.navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        if(item.itemId != binding.navView.selectedItemId)
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
        true
    }
```

where **binding.navView** is the reference for **BottomNavigationView** using Android Data Binding.

Comment: In this case you can do simply `binding.navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {  }`

Comment: You can use `navView.setOnItemReselectedListener {  }` instead of deprecated `navView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {  }`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Jetpack, the easiest way to solve this is using `ViewModel`

You have to save all valuable data and not make unnecessary database loads or network calls everytime you go to a fragment from another.

`UI controllers such as activities and fragments are primarily intended to display UI data, react to user actions, or handle operating system communication, such as permission requests.`

Here is when we use `ViewModels`

`ViewModel objects are automatically retained during configuration changes so that data they hold is immediately available to the next activity or fragment instance.`

So if the fragment is recreated, all your data will be there instantly instead of make another call to database or network. Its important to know that if the activity or fragment that holds the `ViewModel` is reacreated, you will receive the same `ViewModel` instance created before.

But in this case you have to specify the ViewModel to have activity scope instead of fragment scope, independently if you are using a shared ViewModel for all the fragments, or a different ViewModel for every fragment.

Here is a little example using [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) too:

```
//Using KTX
val model by activityViewModels<MyViewModel>()
model.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<DataModel>{ data ->
        // update UI
    })

//Not using KTX
val model by lazy {ViewModelProvider(activity as ViewModelStoreOwner)[MyViewModel::class.java]}
model.getData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<DataModel>{ data ->
        // update UI
    })
```

And that's it! Google is actively working on multiple back stack support for bottom tab Navigation and claim that it'll arrive on `Navigation 2.4.0` as said [here](https://twitter.com/ianhlake/status/1156029527811739650) and [on this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80029773#comment77) if you want and/or your problem is more related to multiple back stack, you can check out those links

Remember fragments still be recreated, usually you don't change component behavior, instead, you adapt your data to them!

I leave you some useful links:

[ViewModel Overview Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

[How to communicate between fragments and activities with ViewModels - on Medium](https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c)

[Restoring UI State using ViewModels - on Medium](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-persistence-onsaveinstancestate-restoring-ui-state-and-loaders-fc7cc4a6c090)

Comment: What if our bottom navigation View fragment keeps showing full screen fragments? Lets say 3 levels deep for that single tab. Then wouldn't you need a viewModel essentially recording which fragment the user is on? And then quickly recreate these fragments on the fly when it gets created again? Seems like a lot of work and needing to mess around with navigation stacks which is less than ideal

Comment: the docs say this is the way to go. though im not really sure if it is. i tried a simple int tracking, it always resets back to its initial value instead of the incremented one. the docs itself is fairly limited it does not even provide a simple working example.

Answer (score 4):

Quick tip, if you just want to prevent loading the already selected fragment just override `setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener` and do nothing, but this won't save the fragment states

```
binding.navBar.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the old version, you just use version **2.4.0-alpha05** or above.
This answer is updated in 2021.

```
androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.4.0-alpha05
androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-alpha05
androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-alpha05
```

Comment: Does this implementations only stops the fragment refresh ? Seems not working. Can you provide any snippet or something working ?

Comment: this works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you use `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()`, the `NavOptions` are defined for you with `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()`. These options include `launchSingleTop` and, if the menu item is not secondary, a `popUpTo` the root of the graph.

The problem is, that `launchSingleTop` still replaces the top fragment with a new one. To resolve this issue, you'd have to create your own `setupWithNavController()` and `onNavDestinationSelected()` functions. In `onNavDestinationSelected()` you'd just adapt the `NavOptions` to your needs.

Comment: Do you have some working sample that demonstrates this approach? I was looking at [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) and [here](https://github.com/STAR-ZERO/navigation-keep-fragment-sample), would these solve this problem?

Comment: I actually replaced the fragment navigator to only show and hide the fragments. Before I tried to do what I suggested here and it worked as well. But it was a different use-case. You could also use actions to define the behavior then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using navigation component,In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/9061224) From version:'2.4.0-alpha01' it has inbuilt support for multiple back stacks.So no navigation extension is needed

refer to this link for more details.  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
```

And

```
private val onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.home -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(homeFragment).commit()
            active = homeFragment
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.news -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(newsFragment).commit()
            active = newsFragment
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.markets -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(marketsFragment).commit()
            active = marketsFragment
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.explore -> {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(exploreFragment).commit()
            active = exploreFragment
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: Do I need to set the `fragments` in `supportFragmentManager` before I try to navigate between them in a listener?

Comment: Yeah. Set all of them in OnCreate(...) of your Activity. Make sure default is Active & rest others are Hidden

Comment: OnViewCreated will be executed either way. It will always be called distegarding how you are using fragmentManager - classic way or via jetpack navigation.

Comment: Make sure you get the references to your fragments by first checking for their existence via `FindFragmentByTag`, and that you track the active fragment tag using onSaveInstanceState / onCreate(Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

create a class:

```
@Navigator.Name("keep_state_fragment") // `keep_state_fragment` is used in navigation xml 
class KeepStateNavigator(
private val context: Context,
private val manager: FragmentManager, // Should pass childFragmentManager.
private val containerId: Int
) : FragmentNavigator(context, manager, containerId) {

override fun navigate(
    destination: Destination,
    args: Bundle?,
    navOptions: NavOptions?,
    navigatorExtras: Navigator.Extras?
): NavDestination? {
    val tag = destination.id.toString()
    val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()

    var initialNavigate = false
    val currentFragment = manager.primaryNavigationFragment
    if (currentFragment != null) {
        transaction.detach(currentFragment)
    } else {
        initialNavigate = true
    }

    var fragment = manager.findFragmentByTag(tag)
    if (fragment == null) {
        val className = destination.className
        fragment = manager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(context.classLoader, className)
        transaction.add(containerId, fragment, tag)
    } else {
        transaction.attach(fragment)
    }

    transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment)
    transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true)
    transaction.commitNow()

    return if (initialNavigate) {
        destination
    } else {
        null
    }
}
}
```

Use keep_state_fragment instead of fragment in nav_graph

In Activity:

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    // get fragment
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)!!
    // setup custom navigator
    val navigator = KeepStateNavigator(this, navHostFragment.childFragmentManager, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.navigatorProvider += navigator

    // set navigation graph
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
    bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The fragment is always null and so a new instance is created even though I used <keep_state_fragment> inside navGraph. Seemed an elegant approach, but not working :/

Besides, navController.navigatorProvider gives warning:

NavController.setNavigatorProvider can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=androidx.navigation)

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet:

```
private fun attachFragment(fragmentTag: String) {
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)?.let {
        if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) return
        val currentFragmentTag = supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount - 1).name
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag) as? FragmentBase)?.let { curFrag ->
            fragmentTransaction.hide(curFrag)
        }
        fragmentTransaction.show(it)
    } ?: run {
        when (fragmentTag) {
            FragmentHome.TAG -> FragmentBase.newInstance<FragmentHome>()
            FragmentAccount.TAG -> FragmentBase.newInstance<FragmentAccount>()
            else -> null
        }?.let {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, it, fragmentTag)
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag)
        }
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

You can use this pass the tag of specific fragment that you want to show now, using method `attachFragment(FragmentHome.TAG)`

Answer (score 0):

**Hi friend, it's new solution:**

```
BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);

binding.navView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() != binding.navView.getSelectedItemId())
                    NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the best way to handle this and finally i came out with this simple idea : deactivate the MenuItem currently selected.

This way, you cannot click twice on it and therefore reloading the fragment is prevented.

Don't forget to Enable it back when you go to another fragment through your navHost.

The mechanic is based on the NavHostFragment which receives your BottomNavigationView from within a fragment/activity.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    navHostFragment =
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

    val navView: BottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    //Here you link the NavHostFragment's navController to your 
    //bottomMenu
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    //Add a listener monitoring the destination changes
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(object : NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener{
        override fun onDestinationChanged(
            controller: NavController,
            destination: NavDestination,
            arguments: Bundle?
        ) {
            /* Disable the selected item and re-enable the others */
            for( item in navView.menu.iterator()){
                item.isEnabled = item.itemId != navView.selectedItemId
            }
        }

    })
}
```

Hoping it might help

Lenzy

Answer (score 0):

Try this: For ChipNavigationBar

```
private void Bottom_navigation() {
        final Fragment fragment1 = new home_fragment();
        final Fragment fragment2 = new bottom_nav1_Bookmark_Fragment();
        final Fragment fragment3 = new bottom_nav1_Search_Fragment();
        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

 ChipNavigationBar chipNavigationBar = findViewById(R.id.chipNavigation);
        chipNavigationBar.setItemSelected(R.id.home, true);


        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame,fragment1, "1").commit();

        chipNavigationBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ChipNavigationBar.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(int i) {
                Fragment active = fragment1;
                Fragment fragment = null;
                switch (i) {
                    case R.id.home:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                        active = fragment1;
                        chipNavigationBar.animate().translationY(0);

                        break;
                    case R.id.tajbi:

                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                        active = fragment2;

                        break;
                    case R.id.more_App:
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                        active = fragment3;
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by using this solution.

First, declare fragments that are used in the bottom navigation view.

```
val fragment1: Fragment = HomeFragment()
val fragment2: Fragment = ProfileFragment()
val fragment3: Fragment = SettingsFragment()
val fm: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
var active = fragment1
```

Now you need to setup the bottom navigation like this

```
  private fun setUpBottomNavigation() {
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainHostFragment, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainHostFragment, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainHostFragment,fragment1, "1").commit();
    val navigation = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottomNavigationView) as BottomNavigationView
    navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
}

private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
    NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener  { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.homeFragment -> {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit()
                active = fragment1
            }
            R.id.assessmentListFragment -> {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit()
                active = fragment2
            }
            R.id.settingsFragment -> {
                supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit()
                active = fragment3
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Comment: How can i achieve to mark bottom navigation view item selected?