# Fragment in fragment with navController

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

In my app I'm using navController to switch between fragments. I have a problem with this scenario:

- ItineraryFragment is opened (at the top of the screen it is a horizontal recyclerview with some days and below the recyclerView it is another fragment); the fragment contained is filled with the attractions corresponding to the first day of the list
- When another day from the recyclerView is clicked, the fragment changes its content with the attractions corresponding to that day

[UI example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7Po.jpg)

Is it possible to create this behavior using only navigation components? Now the nested fragment is put into a FrameLayout using fragmentTransaction but I'd like to use only navController.

Comment: Currently Navigation component does not support multiple back stacks out of the box. But you can create a extension function as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/9715339

Comment: See [nested navigation graphs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs) ...