# How to keep a specific screen when using Navigatioin Component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-bottomnav

I have a `BottomNavigationView` and I am using a `NavController` to switch `menus` and move the `screen`.

I would like to know how to keep a specific screen even when moving the menu freely.

Let me explain in more detail.

There are bottom menus `A, B, C`. And each has a `Fragment` screen.

All menus and screen transitions use `NavHost`, `NavController`, and `nav_graph`.

In menu `C`, a `dialog` is displayed through the `button` on the `C` screen.

The dialog is also linked to the `nav_graph`.

When an option is selected in the dialog, it moves to screen `D`.

`D` screen is the page where you write something.

This is important from now on.

The current menu is `C`, screen `D` is open, and something is being written.

However, if you go to `another menu` while writing and then return to `C`, screen `C` of the first menu `C` appears, not the screen you are writing.

Here, I want the screen I was writing to continue to be displayed even when I return from another menu.

Any good way?

For reference, since I am using the `mvvm` pattern and `viewmodel`, the data of the screen I am writing seems to be maintained.

Thank you.

***nav_graph***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/calendar">

    <!-- menu C screen   -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/write_home"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WriteRoutineHomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_write_routine_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_write_routine_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_write_home_to_bodyPartDialog"
            app:destination="@id/bodyPartDialog" />
    </fragment>

    <!-- dialog -->
    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/bodyPartDialog"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.BodyPartDialogFragment"
        android:label="BodyPartDialogFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_body_part_dialog">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_bodyPartDialog_to_write"
            app:destination="@id/write"/>
    </dialog>

    <!-- screen D (write page) -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/write"
        android:name="com.example.writeweight.fragment.WriteRoutineFragment"
        android:label="WritingRoutineFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_writing_routine">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_write_to_workoutListTabFragment"
            app:destination="@id/workoutListTabFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="title"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null"/>
        <argument
            android:name="workout"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: I don't really like this multiple navigation graph files approach given on most of such answers, I find it a hack as well instead of a proper solution. 

Basically, you want to maintain the state of the fragments. Two ways to do this: First one is easy and more popular, use a ViewPager/2. It will provide the functionality you want without messing up with things. Second, if you want to stick with NavGraph, then, create a custom Navigator to hide the fragment overriding the FragmentManager instead of replacing the fragment. Second one is a little complicated but gives more control.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop fragment refresh in bottom nav using navhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069786/stop-fragment-refresh-in-bottom-nav-using-navhost)

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thanks for suggesting different ways. Let me ask you a question about each of your two answers.

In the `first answer` you said to use `ViewPager2`. By the way, I'm using `BottomNav`, isn't this more like a `Tab` than a `Viewpager`? Does it make a difference if the `menu` is at the `top` or at the `bottom`? Is there any reason it's a `ViewPager`?

In the `second answer`, are you saying that I should make my own `Navigator` that uses `show/hide` method instead of `replace`? To be honest, I have no idea what you're talking about. It's hard.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar 
Oh, I saw the link now. Is the link the solution to your `answer 2`?

Comment: For the suggestion of `ViewPager`/`ViewPager2`, it is used in place of `fragment` in the layout and it can hold multiple fragments in the memory at a time which maintains the current state of the fragments and it can be used with `TabView`, `BottomNav`, `NavigationDrawer` or without any other widget, so when you switch to other tab on `BottomNavigationBar`, it shifts to other tab but maintains the first's state, it's done by setting the [`offscreenPageLimit`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT_DEFAULT).

Comment: For the second one, it's not hard but limited. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142496/8244632) of the link I've provided will help you achieving the solution without shifting to any other thing. Check that out.

Comment: So if I want to use a 'ViewPager' then I have to use 'ViewPager' instead of 'Fragment' in layout? Of course, the bottom is set to 'BottomNavigationView'. And the second answer I said was about the second method of the first answer you wrote (about how to make a 'show/hide Navigator'). Sorry to confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix this issue either use version_navigation 2.4.0-alpha01 which is the easiest way or use NavigationExtensions
to use NavigationExtensions you have to add this to your project [NavigationExtensions](https://github.com/matthewzhang007/android-architecture-components/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) and then in the navigation menu create separate navigation files for each tab.
In the main activity, layout replace fragment with FragmentContainerView and remove NavHostFragment.

In the Mainactivty

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener {
private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()
private var currentNavController: LiveData<NavController>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    /*
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        // navController.graph,
        setOf(
             R.id.navigate_home, R.id.navigate_collection, R.id.navigate_profile
        ),
        drawerLayout
    )

    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)

    // make sure appbar/toolbar is not hidden upon fragment switch
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        if (destination.id in bottomNavDestinationIds) {
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)
        }
    }
     */
     // Add your tab fragments

    val navGraphIds = listOf(R.navigation.home, R.navigation.albumlist, R.navigation.test)
    val controller = bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(
        navGraphIds = navGraphIds,
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager,
        containerId = R.id.nav_host_container,
        intent = intent
    )
    // Whenever the selected controller changes, setup the action bar.
    controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->

        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        // optional NavigationView for Drawer implementation
        // navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        addOnDestinationChangedListener(navController)
    })
    currentNavController = controller
}

private fun addOnDestinationChangedListener(navController: NavController) {
    // ensure only one listener is active
    navController.removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
}

override fun onDestinationChanged(
    controller: NavController,
    destination: NavDestination,
    arguments: Bundle?
) {
    if (destination.id in bottomNavDestinationIds) {
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true)
    }
}}
```

Comment: I also looked into `navigation 2.4.0-alpha01`. But I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what's different.

Comment: Check out this article https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-multiple-back-stacks-6c67ba41952f