# Fragments are always recreated when used with Android navigation from jetpack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am facing this issue of fragments recreation with Android navigation component. I have integrated bottom navigation and coupled it with the android navigation component. So, every time I click on a tab on bottom bar, the fragment is recreated and the old state is not persisted.

I want to retain the state of fragment even when I go to other tabs and come back. I am not finding any solution for it anywhere.

Except bottom navigation, I am using `navController.navigate()` method to navigate between different fragments.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51684125/6908588) answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Hi the problem is fixed in latest version 2.4.0-alpha01  now there is a support multiple backstack navigation

Checkout the link:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_240_2

Comment: How this fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Navigation to handle multiple back stacks. A similar solution to this problem is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195906/10133501)

You can also use [ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to preserve the view state.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use hide/show fragment instead of navigation:
[Show hide fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android)